# Connectedness of a subset of structured matrices satisfying prescribed conditions on roots of polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, general-topology, polynomials, connectedness

I am extracting information of me proving an application problem, if there is anything not clear, please let me know.

Suppose we parameterize a structured matrix in following form
\begin{align}
\label{matrix:1}
\tag{$\star$}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -a_1 & 0 & 0 & -b_1 \\
1 & -a_2 & 0 & 0 & -b_2 \\
0 & -a_3 & 0 & 0 & -b_3 \\
0 & -a_4 & 1 & 0 & -b_4 \\
0 & -a_5 & 0 &1 & -b_5
\end{pmatrix},
\end{align}
where the upper left $2 \times 2$ and lower right $3 \times 3$ blocks are in [companion form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix).

> > I would like to claim that the set of matrices of above form and with eigenvalues modules bounded in some interval $(-M, M)$ is connected. If we let
> >     \begin{align*}
> >  E = \{ A \in \mathcal{M}(5 \times 5; \mathbb R): \text{ $A$ is of form \eqref{matrix:1} and } \rho(A) < M \},
> > \end{align*}
> >     we want to prove $E$ is connected.

My approach is to first prove the set
\begin{align*}
 F = \{ B \in \mathcal{M}(5 \times 5; \mathbb R): \text{ structure of $B$ is of the form \eqref{matrix:2} and } \rho(B) < M \}
\end{align*}
is connected,
where
\begin{align}
\label{matrix:2}
\tag{$\ast$}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -a_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & -a_2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -b_3 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -b_4 \\
0 &  0 & 0 &1 & -b_5
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
If a matrix $C$ has the form \eqref{matrix:2}, then the characteristic polynomial $p_C(t) = (t^2+a_2 t + a_1)(t^3 + b_5 t^2 + b_4 t +b_3)$. If I am not mistaken, the set $F$ should be a continuous image of roots lying in $(-M, M)$ which should be connected. Now I would like to show for a general element in $E$, we can find a continuous path to the set $F$. Since for any $A \in E$, the characteristic polynomial 
$$p_A(t) = (t^2+a_2 t + a_1)(t^3 + b_5 t^2 + b_4 t +b_3) + \text{ polynomial terms involving entries of } a, b.$$
Intuitively, we can first choose some element $D \in F$ with $p_D(t) = p_A(t)$ and then continuously transform the coefficients there. But now I could not prove the whole path will only contain elements of $E$.

Would anyone help me with this approach or provide some other approaches? Or given examples to show the set is actually not connected?

Comment: What is the difference between sets $E$ and $F$? Their definitions seem to be identical.

Comment: They have different structures. $F$ is of $(*)$ form. Also, the end goal is to show $E$ is connected and I tried to show $F$ first. It does not have to relate to $F$.

Comment: My bad, I somehow didn't notice that top-right block is zero for ($\ast$).

Comment: Are you assuming the eigenvalues are real?

Comment: No. They could be complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $r\ne 0$ and consider the matrix 
$$
A_r:=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & - r^2 a_1 & 0 & 0 & - r^2 b_1 \\
1 & - r a_2 & 0 & 0 & - r b_2 \\
0 & - r^3 a_3 & 0 & 0 & - r^3 b_3 \\
0 & - r^2 a_4 & 1 & 0 & - r^2 b_4 \\
0 & - r  a_5 & 0 &1 & - r b_5
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then the characteristic polynomial $P_{A_r}$ of $A_r$ satisfies
$$
P_{A_r}(rx)=r^5 P_A(x).
$$
Hence, $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of  $A$ if and only if $r\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A_r$.

Now it is easy to connect two matrices $A_0,A_1$ in $E=E_M$:

Take the continuous path $A_t=tA_1+(1-t)A_0$  from $A_0$ to $A_1$. Since the path is compact, there is an $N>0$ such that $\rho(A_t)<N$ for all $t$. If $N\le M$, the path lies in $E$. Else set $r:=M/N$ and connect $A_0$ with $(A_0)_r$ via $(A_0)_s$ for $s\in[r,1]$, connect $(A_0)_r$ with $(A_1)_r$ via $(A_t)_r$ for $t\in [0,1]$ and connect $(A_1)_r$ with $A_1$ via $(A_1)_s$ for $s\in[r,1]$. The three paths, concatenated, give the desired path between $A_0$ and $A_1$ in $E$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. May I ask: is there some clever way to see $P_{A_r}(rx) = r^5 P_A(x)$ besides direct computation?

Comment: One can reduce the direct computation a bit using that the determinant is linear in each column, so you have four summands, one is the determinant $det(A-xr I)$ of a matrix $A$ in F, two are zero, and the fourth is $$det\begin{pmatrix}
-x r & 0 & 0 & 0 & - r^2 b_1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & - r b_2 \\
0 & - r^3 a_3 & -x r & 0 &0\\
0 & - r^2 a_4 & 1 & -x r & 0 \\
0 & - r  a_5 & 0 &1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: So you need only to prove the property for each of the two determinants.

Comment: Your answer is fantastic. May I ask: how do you come up the idea?

Comment: I was just lucky. I was trying to do something with the Jacobian matrix (kind of implicit function theorem) of $\partial c/\partial ab$ and $\partial c/\partial ba$, where $c$ is the vector of coefficients of the characteristic polynomial, $ab=(a_1,a_2,b_3,b_4,b_5)$ and $ba=(b_1,b_2,a_3,a_4,a_5)$ and I noticed that the matrix was in some vague sense homogenous. Then I was able to pin down that homogenousity.

Comment: This method is so brilliant. What makes you to consider taking the Jacobian matrix? More interesting to me, why you group the coefficients in such way $(a_1, a_2, b_3, b_4, b_5)$ and $(b_1, b_2, a_3, a_4, a_5)$?

Comment: I was trying to go from F to E. The matrix in F corresponds to $(a_1,a_2,b_3,b_4,b_5)$.

Comment: This should be a separate question. But if possible, could you comment on the connectedness of the set $\{A \in M_5(\mathbb R): A \text{ is of form } \star \text{ and } \text{Re}(\lambda_i(A))  < 0 \text{ for } i = 1, \dots, n\}$? I would you reward another bounty if you can help me on this. It seems to me we could not generalize the method above. Thanks.

Comment: The geometric idea should be easy: First connect a given matrix in that set with another matrix in that set, but wiht five different eigenvalues. Then deform the eigenvectors of one of the matrices into the eigenvectors of the other. Finally transform the eigenvalues of one into the eigenvalues of the other and you are done.

Comment: The first and the third step are easy: The first step follows from the facts that the matrices with five different eigenvalues are dense and that the condition $Re(\lambda_i(A))<0$ is open. The third step follows from the fact that you can connect linearly the matrices in diagonal form if all the entries satisfy $Re(\lambda_i(A))<0$. The second step is tricky,  geometrically the idea is to take $A=P D P^{-1}$ where $P$ is invertible and $D$ diagonal. Similarly $B=QD_1 Q^{-1}$ and $D_1$ diagonal. The columns of $P$ are the  eigenvectors of $A$, the columns of $Q$ are the eigenv. of $B$.

Comment: Now take a continuous path in the invertible matrices from $P$ to $Q$, say $P_t$. Then $P_t D (P_t)^{-1}$ connects $A$ with $Q D Q^{-1}$. Finally connect $D$ linearly with $D_1$ (third step).

Comment: I thought about this idea. The main problem was step $2$. How do we know we can choose a path from $P$ to $Q$. I know $GL_n(\mathbb C)$ is connected but since the matrix is real we have certain restrictions on the path. And also we need to guarantee $P_t D (P_t)^{-1}$ to end up with the structure of $\star$.

Comment: I forgot to mention another problem here: $D_1$ and $D_2$ might have different number of complex values and then the convex combination will not be invariant under conjugation.

Comment: You are right, the path is not in star. But the second problem is solved in the first step, you can assume 5 different eigenvalues.

Comment: I mean if $D_1$ has $1$ complex pair and $D_2$ has all real numbers. If they are different, I think the linear combination will not come in conjugate pairs.

Comment: I just saw that I missed that the matrices are real.